# What was life like for Victorian linen weavers in Scotland?

Tags: clothing, scotland, victorian, occupations

I'm doing my family history and have found people who worked as linen weavers in Angus, Scotland.

I'd like to know more about what life was like for them. Were linen weavers well-off? How much money did they make? How did they sell their goods? Were they unskilled or highly skilled and if so were their skills appreciated or were they part of lower-class, unlike other craftsmen?

Comment: They were often very skilled, but also quite low-paid.This [paper](http://www.thedayfamily.org.uk/history/Fife.htm) describes the situation in Fife, but the situation in Angus would have been much the same.